# How do you select CSV file to perform calculations on based on user input?

Tags: java, csv, user-interface

I'm currently making a user-input based program on Java Eclipse that is supposed perform calculations on data from a local csv file the user selects. The GUI code below is the source code that I have been using to make the GUI for the program. While I have managed to create the GUI, I am having trouble with "combining" the code listed under "CSVReader," which is a class I created, with the code for the GUI so that the user can select the CSV file. The user is supposed to select this CSV file by typing its path name into the text field box on the GUI.

Any help would be appreciated

GUI CODE

```
//GUI CODE
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame1 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField txtCountryChosen;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=71,14
     */
    private final JTextField Program = new JTextField();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        Program.setText("Statistics Manager");
        Program.setColumns(10);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit file path");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 String textFieldValue = textField.getText();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(145, 48, 150, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(116, 13, 200, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Mean GDP");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(0, 154, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Mean GDP_per_capita");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(250, 154, 170, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Mean pop");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(109, 154, 120, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);
        
        txtCountryChosen = new JTextField();
        txtCountryChosen.setBounds(42, 104, 116, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtCountryChosen);
        txtCountryChosen.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("Select country");
        btnNewButton_4.setBounds(270, 103, 150, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_4);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Print Results in Txt File");
        btnNewButton_5.setBounds(131, 201, 200, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_5);
    }
}
```

CSVReader

```
//CSVREADER
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class CSVReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter file path name");
    String file_path_name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(file_path_name);
        
        
        String path= file_path_name;
        String line = "";
        
        
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                System.out.println("Country: " + values[0] + ", Year: " + values[2] + ", GDP: " + values[6] + ", GDP_per_capita: " + values[12] + ", Population: " + values[10]);
                /*PrintStream myconsole= new PrintStream(new File("E://java.txt"));
                System.setOut(myconsole);
                myconsole.print(path);*/
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Swing application should only have a single main() method. Then methods in your application can prompt for user data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Chooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for an example of display a file dialog to select a file. Once the file is selected you do your custom processing.

Comment: I don't know the language very well; I'm learning it as I go and I have hardly any coaching aside from youtube tutorials (which in this case don't help). If you have any idea what to add to the code, can you please help

Comment: I know there's only supposed to be one main method...is there any way I can edit the code so that I'm left with one main method?

Comment: What part of the tutorial code do you not understand? There are working examples to download and use as your starting code. Then you customize the code to add more functionality.

Comment: The main thing I have trouble with is making it so that the user can input a file path name into the first text field in the GUI (that I couldn't post a screenshot of). I need to select the CSV file associated with the path name after the user has clicked a button (which should be triggered by an action listener).

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. There are some subtleties to handling CSV correctly. What will your code do with a CSV line like `"Smith, John ""Jack""",2010/12/20,"123 Main St, Denver, CO 80010",M` -- There are excellent CSV libraries out there, use one of them and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: The tutorial shows how to use a JFileChooser to allow the user to select a file. Why are you still talking about a text field? Why would you force the user to know the exact location and file name? The point of the file chooser is this it will display all the .csv files in a directory that your program specifies. Then the user just selects the file they want. Learn to use the features of Swing.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked with file chooser